# If a person pray Asr salah on the time of hanafi madhab, is this haram or not?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, hanafi

Assalamualaikum, I actually wanted to know, is praying salah on the time of hanafi madhab Haram? I heard shiekh Assim Al Hakeem say that this is not how Prophet Muhammad SA used to pray and they used to pray on the time of other madhabs told, so will this be sinful?
Edit : I want to know whether this would be haram or not because it's not the way of prophet Muhammad.

Comment: You can pray Asr during the time of Asr. As long as it's before the ending time it's okay.

Comment: Why should it be? The prophet himself was taught to pray at the two edges of the prayer time of each prayer by Jibreel. The issue is not the 'asr prayer for hanafi, but delaying the dhuhr prayer could be an issue for them, because the time for the hanafi school of fiqh starts much later as that of the other schools.